# Android AnimationDrawable Recycling issue

Tags: android, animationdrawable

I have a AnimationDrawable that i initialise before starting the animation and recycle it right as it finishes.. the problem is that when i want to start the animation again, i reinitialise everything but still gives an exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@2bbad018
```

here's my code

```
 public ImageView radarImageView;
 public AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;

    public void animationStart() {

//        animationStop();

        radarImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.radarIV);
        radarImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sensor_animation);
        animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) radarImageView.getBackground();

        animationDrawable.start();
    }

    public void animationStop() {

        animationDrawable.stop();

        for (int i = 0; i < animationDrawable.getNumberOfFrames(); ++i){
            Drawable frame = animationDrawable.getFrame(i);
            if (frame instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                ((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap().recycle();
            }
            frame.setCallback(null);
        }
        animationDrawable.setCallback(null);

//        animationDrawable = null;
//        radarImageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
```

Why does it not reinitialise the whole thing again?

Comment: Why do you need to recycle the bitmap? calling `animationDrawable.stop()` is not enough for you?

Comment: stop() doesn't release the memory.. thats why i need to call recycel

Comment: The problem is that because when you call recycle on the bitmap you cannot reuse it. and because you are calling `setBackgroundResources(R.drawable. sensor_animation)` you are referring to the same object which its bitmaps were recycled previously. You either have to create a new drawable every time or do not recycle the instace

Comment: Thank you hoomi.. this is the only sensible answer i was able to find since 2 days,.. u saved my day bro

Comment: No problem. Should I make it an answer so you can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because when you `Bitmap.recycle()` is called on the bitmap you cannot reuse it.

Also as you are calling `setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.sensor_animation)` you are referring to the same object which its bitmaps were recycled previously.

As a solution, you either have to create a new drawable every time or do not recycle that instance.

If you are worries about the memory usage try to use smaller bitmaps. Also using the correct sizes for different screen densities would help.